# UK visa payment pending message

Tags: visas, uk, payment

I have submitted an on-line Standard visitor UK visa application for my 1 year old son.

I made the payment today morning (using internet explorer browser), using my credit card which has been charged. However, I did not receive any confirmation e-mail. If I log into the application a message appears which says "Payment pending - your payment is being processed". I need to make sure that my submission is complete before I show up for the appointment with my child.

Please note that I also submitted another application for my daughter using the same credit card, which has gone through successfully and for which I received the confirmation e-mail instantaneously.

Please let me know what options i have, as I do not want to miss the appointment which is in a weeks time, and there is also no option to postpone / withdraw it as the payment is still under process.

Comment: Did you have any success with that? We're in the same situation right now.

Comment: It did eventually go through but after like a month. No point in emailing them , they would just send you a standard reply. Call them (although it’s charged by the minute) most probably they will ask you to submit a fresh application and refund the money for this one within 28 days.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Too bad I already called them two times and wasted something like 15 GBP on the same exact advice. It's quite weird you have to pay them more because their payment system doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP:

> It did eventually go through but after like a month. No point in emailing them , they would just send you a standard reply. Call them (although it’s charged by the minute) most probably they will ask you to submit a fresh application and refund the money for this one within 28 days.

Comment: @NikunjLahoti if you read this, you don't need 'karma' (reputation) to post answers (cf. https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/110805)